# Creating an HTML file by combining multiple PHP files via the command line?

Tags: php, command-line

Is it possible to combine multiple PHP files via the command line and create an HTML file?

For example, this will save the rendered version of a single PHP file as HTML:

```
php /path/to/my/file/filename.php > /path/to/my/file/test.html
```

I need it to combine multiple files, but I can't seem to get it it to work. Ideally, it would be something like this:

```
php /path/to/my/file/filename.php + /path/to/my/file/filename2.php + /path/to/my/file/filename3.php > /path/to/my/file/test.html
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could do:

```
php file.php > someFile.html
php file2.php >> someFile.html
php file3.php >> someFile.html
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `>>` to append output in bash.

```
touch /path/to/my/file/test.html
php /path/to/my/file/filename.php >> /path/to/my/file/test.html
php /path/to/my/file/filename2.php >> /path/to/my/file/test.html
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may be looking for is
`cat file1.php file2.php file3.php | php > file.html`

Comment: possible problem with global variables